# How do I enable mutual SSL in IIS7 with a self-signed certificate?

Tags: iis-7, ssl-certificate, self-signed

I've created a self-signed certificate in IIS7. Then I exported this certificate to a .pfx and then installed it on the client machine's IE browser. Then I set "Require Client Certificate" on the server's IIS configuration. When I try to visit the site with IE, a dialog box comes up for me to choose a certificate, however, there are no certs in that dialog box. When I click "OK" without choosing any certs, I get a 403 forbidden error. How can I make this work? Appreciate the help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you dont set the "Require Client Certificate"? If you recieve the "There is a problem..." page. Then there is some issue with the internet explorer not trusting your certificate. If it's not trusting it, it wont use it to authenticate( I think).

Comment: It seems that self-signed certificates have these issues with IE because there is no Certificate authority. Once I created a certificate authority and added it to my trusted certs store. It worked. When I added the self-signed certificate to my trusted certs, though, it didn't work.